# QString::number result is wrong

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I was practicing converting numbers in Qt and ran into a problem. I have a variable of type int - `result`, its value is, for example, 11111 (I get it in a certain way).  I want this number to be considered binary in my program.  To do this, I'm trying to translate it into a string in variable `res` and add "0b" in front of my value, like

```
QString res = "0b" + QString:number(result);
```

My variable `res` is "0b11111" and that's right, but I want to get a variable of type int, so I'm trying to cast a string to it:

```
result = res.toInt();
```

and in the end I get 0. I understand that this is most likely due to the second character "b", but is there really no way to convert the number to the binary system as it is?
Or did I made a mistake somewhere?
Thank you for all answers, that could helps me to understand what’s wrong!

Comment: So you have an integer variables with the value eleven thousand one hundred and eleven, but you want it to be considered binary and therefore a value of fifteen? Can't help thinking that you are solving the wrong problem, but convert to a `std::string` and then use the `std::stoi` function which allows you to specify binary.

Comment: I think problem is assumption that `result` containing `11111` value is an actual binary value. Debugger and `QString:number` are assuring that you wish to see value in decimal format (since you are a human). Actual binary representation of `result` is `0b10101101100111`. To convert value to text which uses some specific base use: `QString:number(result, 2);`.

Comment: my idea was to convert the binary number (8+) characters to the decimal system, for further transmission, as it is displayed incorrectly

Comment: Thanks all! Stuck and confused after 20 hours of work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Qt, you can specify the base, if you look carefully at the [`QString` documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#toInt), you could simply write:

```
res = QString::number(11111);
result = res.toInt(nullptr, 2); // Base 2
```

Or even better:

```
bool success; // Can be used to check if the conversion succeeded

res = QString::number(11111);
result = res.toInt(&success, 2);
```

Comment: I tried that form (result = res.toInt(nullptr, 2); ), but it get 0 too

Comment: @Helkot It's what given by the documentation, and works for me. So _"it doesn't work"_ is not enough to understand what you missed. My guess is that your forgot to remove the leading "0b" that is of no use here. If you really want to keep it, then use base `0` instead of `2`. Again, read the doc :)

Comment: In my real situation, I get an 8 digit number that I want to convert to decimal, but didn’t work out

Comment: I read documentation before I came here, that my last hope T_T

Comment: @Helkot If you want to interpret a `QString` as a binary number, this is the way to go. And it works just fine. You must have done a mistake. Show your code, we'll see what's wrong.

Comment: So I appreciate your response and your time, I will try to understand at what point the difference from the ideal went, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order for the [`QString.toInt()` function](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#toInt) to use the "C Convention" and determine which base to use according to known prefixes (the "0b" in your case), you need to explicitly specify a base of zero in the call:

```cpp
QString res = "0b" + QString:number(result);
result = res.toInt(nullptr, 0); // If "base" is zero, parse/use the "0b"
```

Otherwise, if no "base" argument is given, it will default to 10 (i.e. decimal) and, in that case, only the leading zero in your string will be parsed, because the 'b' character is not a valid decimal digit.

Alternatively, you can skip the leading `"0b"` characters and explicitly tell the function to use base 2:

```cpp
QString res = QString:number(result); // No added "0b" prefix
result = res.toInt(nullptr, 2);       // Force use of binary
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time and answer!

Answer (score 0):

So you have an integer variables with the value eleven thousand one hundred and eleven, but you want it to be considered binary and therefore a value of thirty one? Can't help thinking that you are solving the wrong problem.

But anyway, convert to a `std::string` using `std::to_string` and then use the `std::stoi` function to convert back to an integer. `std::stoi` allows you to specify binary a binary conversion.

```
int result = 11111;
int res = std::stoi(std::to_string(result), nullptr, 2);
std::cout << res << '\n';
```

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, fixed.